# What to do with good not-examples

Tags: discussion, documentation

Take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/3659/extending-vim#t=20160725130853206271), the example `What is a plugin?` clearly is not an example.

But the content is important and *good* so I do not want to flag the example as *not an example* because

> This was posted as an example, but it does not attempt to illustrate the topic.

does not match the case. So what should one do? Flag it as *unclear*, because

> This example does not sufficiently illustrate the point and needs to be edited to provide more details.

?
Or just leave the example like that?

Comment: Maybe the title of the example can be improved?

Answer (score 5):

IMO this example can be moved pretty safely to Remarks section, as it pretty much describes the topic without producing actual examples.